# What's the best way to detect punctuation in some user input?? I would like it to be GCSE level please do nothing way too complicated

Tags: python

```
Sentence = input("Type a sentence")

Loop = True

While loop = True:
    If # something to detect punctuati#:               
        Loop = True
    Else:
        Loop = False
```

Comment: Define 'punctuation'. That may help you already.

Answer (score 7):

If you want something simple, you can import `punctuation` from string and then  check if the string contains any punctuation characters.

```
from string import punctuation

my_text = 'What?'

>>> any(p in my_text for p in punctuation)
True
```

**Example**

```
while True: 
    s = raw_input('type a sentence without punctuation: ')  # Python 2
    if not any(p in s for p in punctuation):
        break
```

Comment: That seems quite good but I'm unsure to what the code would be in the context to my program

Comment: Maybe if you explain the context of your solution, we can define that. But this code could be wrapped in a function to be use in some tests like: if hasPunctuation(sentence) is true, then need to break the sentence...

Comment: That's quite good for the time being. Thnx. What does break do again? Does it stop the program?

Comment: Breaks from the `while` loop.

Comment: so the coded example u gave... how would I write an error message on that if there was punctuation or otherwise the program would carry on to the next step if there was no punctuation detected